# Анализ сложного txt файла на языке Python

Tags: python, парсер, csv, анализ

Существует файл для анализа который нужно конвертировать в csv для дальнейшей работы.

```html
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Obs ID:              1 Obs Type:          2 Satellite ID:    15
Latitude:    20.7500 Longitude:  124.5500 Elevation:        0.0
Surface Type:       1 Sat View Angle:  52.8000 Solar Zen Ang:   51.8000
Brightness Temperatures:
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00         192.29         256.61         266.36         252.85
         232.14         220.83         210.75         206.92         215.78
       -9999.00         236.17         245.84       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
 Number of Channels Used =           11
 Channel  Background  Observed   Retrieved          
     22    173.371    192.290    192.044
     23    244.444    256.610    257.050
     24    260.909    266.360    266.592
     25    248.754    252.850    252.235
     26    233.249    232.140    232.383
     27    225.073    220.830    220.043
     28    220.637    210.750    212.271
     29    220.699    206.920    210.254
     30    225.226    215.780    217.249
     32    243.505    236.170    237.239
     33    255.710    245.840    247.568
                          Retrieval                        Background
  Pressure (Pa)  T (K)    q (ppmv)     Ozone        T (K)   q (ppmv)      Ozone
     101325.   298.686  0.2324E+05  0.3016E-01   294.210  0.1877E+05  0.3016E-01
     100543.   298.024  0.2315E+05  0.3037E-01   293.907  0.1841E+05  0.3037E-01
      98588.   297.515  0.2113E+05  0.3090E-01   293.136  0.1751E+05  0.3090E-01
      95744.   295.335  0.1864E+05  0.3170E-01   291.987  0.1621E+05  0.3170E-01
      92246.   293.676  0.1643E+05  0.3274E-01   290.545  0.1465E+05  0.3274E-01
      88280.   292.650  0.1426E+05  0.3397E-01   288.909  0.1299E+05  0.3397E-01
      83995.   291.770  0.1209E+05  0.3541E-01   287.073  0.1126E+05  0.3541E-01
      79509.   290.281  0.9867E+04  0.3726E-01   284.817  0.9380E+04  0.3726E-01
      74912.   287.965  0.7671E+04  0.3973E-01   281.939  0.7414E+04  0.3973E-01
      70273.   285.443  0.5858E+04  0.4271E-01   278.681  0.5757E+04  0.4271E-01
      65643.   282.963  0.4532E+04  0.4599E-01   275.334  0.4513E+04  0.4599E-01
      61060.   280.394  0.3368E+04  0.4967E-01   271.845  0.3384E+04  0.4967E-01
      56554.   277.741  0.2408E+04  0.5391E-01   268.172  0.2415E+04  0.5391E-01
      52146.   275.086  0.1821E+04  0.5890E-01   264.389  0.1822E+04  0.5890E-01
      47854.   272.086  0.1436E+04  0.6566E-01   260.364  0.1439E+04  0.6566E-01
      43695.   268.148  0.1106E+04  0.7502E-01   255.938  0.1105E+04  0.7502E-01
      39681.   262.871  0.8180E+03  0.8441E-01   251.280  0.8060E+03  0.8441E-01
      35828.   256.191  0.5761E+03  0.9632E-01   246.411  0.5696E+03  0.9632E-01
      32150.   247.563  0.3981E+03  0.1121E+00   241.346  0.4033E+03  0.1121E+00
      28660.   237.682  0.2671E+03  0.1265E+00   236.187  0.2713E+03  0.1265E+00
      25371.   227.632  0.1295E+03  0.1632E+00   230.684  0.1305E+03  0.1632E+00
      22294.   219.786  0.4973E+02  0.2049E+00   225.186  0.5026E+02  0.2049E+00
      19436.   213.128  0.1496E+02  0.2509E+00   218.768  0.1510E+02  0.2509E+00
      16795.   209.215  0.6121E+01  0.3555E+00   215.204  0.6136E+01  0.3555E+00
      14384.   208.600  0.4269E+01  0.4708E+00   215.839  0.4273E+01  0.4708E+00
      12204.   206.559  0.3254E+01  0.5346E+00   215.683  0.3256E+01  0.5346E+00
      10205.   203.735  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00   215.618  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00
       8518.   202.842  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00   216.410  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00
       6997.   203.789  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01   217.850  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01
       5673.   205.891  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01   219.586  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01
       4529.   208.559  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01   221.315  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01
       3551.   213.389  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01   223.209  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01
       2726.   220.755  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01   225.229  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01
       2040.   227.335  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01   227.716  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01
       1481.   230.944  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01   231.953  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01
       1037.   232.515  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01   237.296  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01
        695.   235.741  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01   244.054  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01
        441.   240.478  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01   252.245  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01
        261.   252.456  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01   262.152  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01
        142.   268.470  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01   273.944  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01
         69.   267.570  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01   273.136  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01
         29.   252.797  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01   258.509  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01
         10.   229.654  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00   230.264  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00
Surface Temperature (K):         296.249   294.210
Surface Humidity (ppmv):      149826.209 18771.500
Skin Temperature (K):            296.738   294.210
Surface Pressure (Pa):           101325.  101325.

No. of Iterations:               4
Normalised Cost Function:      28.617 Normalised Gradient:       0.007
 --------------------------------------------------------------
Obs ID:              2 Obs Type:          2 Satellite ID:    15
Latitude:    20.7500 Longitude:  126.8000 Elevation:        0.0
Surface Type:       1 Sat View Angle:  44.3000 Solar Zen Ang:   53.6000
Brightness Temperatures:
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00         188.75         252.65         267.39         256.10
         235.62         223.73         212.71         206.01         214.28
       -9999.00         233.71         244.91       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
 Number of Channels Used =           11
 Channel  Background  Observed   Retrieved          
     22    171.377    188.750    189.009
     23    239.373    252.650    252.695
     24    261.765    267.390    267.631
     25    251.970    256.100    255.523
     26    236.281    235.620    235.978
     27    227.105    223.730    222.908
     28    221.555    212.710    213.902
     29    220.202    206.010    209.821
     30    224.417    214.280    215.978
     32    242.015    233.710    235.372
     33    254.149    244.910    246.320
                          Retrieval                        Background
  Pressure (Pa)  T (K)    q (ppmv)     Ozone        T (K)   q (ppmv)      Ozone
     101325.   298.567  0.2335E+05  0.3016E-01   294.210  0.1877E+05  0.3016E-01
     100543.   297.962  0.2319E+05  0.3037E-01   293.907  0.1841E+05  0.3037E-01
      98588.   297.581  0.2090E+05  0.3090E-01   293.136  0.1751E+05  0.3090E-01
      95744.   295.570  0.1817E+05  0.3170E-01   291.987  0.1621E+05  0.3170E-01
      92246.   293.965  0.1582E+05  0.3274E-01   290.545  0.1465E+05  0.3274E-01
      88280.   292.888  0.1363E+05  0.3397E-01   288.909  0.1299E+05  0.3397E-01
      83995.   291.932  0.1156E+05  0.3541E-01   287.073  0.1126E+05  0.3541E-01
      79509.   290.374  0.9471E+04  0.3726E-01   284.817  0.9380E+04  0.3726E-01
      74912.   287.979  0.7422E+04  0.3973E-01   281.939  0.7414E+04  0.3973E-01
      70273.   285.353  0.5714E+04  0.4271E-01   278.681  0.5757E+04  0.4271E-01
      65643.   282.756  0.4453E+04  0.4599E-01   275.334  0.4513E+04  0.4599E-01
      61060.   280.042  0.3332E+04  0.4967E-01   271.845  0.3384E+04  0.4967E-01
      56554.   277.189  0.2399E+04  0.5391E-01   268.172  0.2415E+04  0.5391E-01
      52146.   274.300  0.1824E+04  0.5890E-01   264.389  0.1822E+04  0.5890E-01
      47854.   271.013  0.1442E+04  0.6566E-01   260.364  0.1439E+04  0.6566E-01
      43695.   266.805  0.1114E+04  0.7502E-01   255.938  0.1105E+04  0.7502E-01
      39681.   261.330  0.8274E+03  0.8441E-01   251.280  0.8060E+03  0.8441E-01
      35828.   254.557  0.5835E+03  0.9632E-01   246.411  0.5696E+03  0.9632E-01
      32150.   246.118  0.4021E+03  0.1121E+00   241.346  0.4033E+03  0.1121E+00
      28660.   236.643  0.2688E+03  0.1265E+00   236.187  0.2713E+03  0.1265E+00
      25371.   227.128  0.1296E+03  0.1632E+00   230.684  0.1305E+03  0.1632E+00
      22294.   219.756  0.4966E+02  0.2049E+00   225.186  0.5026E+02  0.2049E+00
      19436.   213.293  0.1504E+02  0.2509E+00   218.768  0.1510E+02  0.2509E+00
      16795.   209.366  0.6097E+01  0.3555E+00   215.204  0.6136E+01  0.3555E+00
      14384.   208.671  0.4285E+01  0.4708E+00   215.839  0.4273E+01  0.4708E+00
      12204.   206.548  0.3248E+01  0.5346E+00   215.683  0.3256E+01  0.5346E+00
      10205.   203.687  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00   215.618  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00
       8518.   202.887  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00   216.410  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00
       6997.   203.997  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01   217.850  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01
       5673.   206.257  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01   219.586  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01
       4529.   209.014  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01   221.315  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01
       3551.   213.848  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01   223.209  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01
       2726.   221.025  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01   225.229  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01
       2040.   226.951  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01   227.716  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01
       1481.   229.618  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01   231.953  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01
       1037.   230.640  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01   237.296  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01
        695.   234.402  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01   244.054  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01
        441.   240.748  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01   252.245  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01
        261.   254.145  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01   262.152  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01
        142.   269.809  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01   273.944  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01
         69.   268.319  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01   273.136  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01
         29.   252.843  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01   258.509  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01
         10.   229.798  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00   230.264  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00
Surface Temperature (K):         296.422   294.210
Surface Humidity (ppmv):      163584.823 18771.500
Skin Temperature (K):            297.157   294.210
Surface Pressure (Pa):           101325.  101325.

No. of Iterations:               4
Normalised Cost Function:      28.650 Normalised Gradient:       0.046
 --------------------------------------------------------------
Obs ID:              3 Obs Type:          2 Satellite ID:    15
Latitude:    20.7500 Longitude:  127.5500 Elevation:        0.0
Surface Type:       1 Sat View Angle:  40.2000 Solar Zen Ang:   54.3000
Brightness Temperatures:
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00         187.32         250.80         267.72         257.30
         237.04         225.02         213.65         205.43         213.97
       -9999.00         233.71         244.35       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
 Number of Channels Used =           11
 Channel  Background  Observed   Retrieved          
     22    169.948    187.320    187.756
     23    237.060    250.800    251.041
     24    261.803    267.720    267.827
     25    253.122    257.300    256.724
     26    237.516    237.040    237.459
     27    227.986    225.020    224.163
     28    222.003    213.650    214.666
     29    220.036    205.430    209.616
     30    224.112    213.970    215.603
     32    241.436    233.710    235.155
     33    253.523    244.350    245.861
                          Retrieval                        Background
  Pressure (Pa)  T (K)    q (ppmv)     Ozone        T (K)   q (ppmv)      Ozone
     101325.   298.564  0.2344E+05  0.3016E-01   294.210  0.1877E+05  0.3016E-01
     100543.   297.970  0.2325E+05  0.3037E-01   293.907  0.1841E+05  0.3037E-01
      98588.   297.615  0.2085E+05  0.3090E-01   293.136  0.1751E+05  0.3090E-01
      95744.   295.632  0.1803E+05  0.3170E-01   291.987  0.1621E+05  0.3170E-01
      92246.   294.019  0.1563E+05  0.3274E-01   290.545  0.1465E+05  0.3274E-01
      88280.   292.908  0.1342E+05  0.3397E-01   288.909  0.1299E+05  0.3397E-01
      83995.   291.908  0.1138E+05  0.3541E-01   287.073  0.1126E+05  0.3541E-01
      79509.   290.301  0.9338E+04  0.3726E-01   284.817  0.9380E+04  0.3726E-01
      74912.   287.842  0.7334E+04  0.3973E-01   281.939  0.7414E+04  0.3973E-01
      70273.   285.149  0.5660E+04  0.4271E-01   278.681  0.5757E+04  0.4271E-01
      65643.   282.489  0.4421E+04  0.4599E-01   275.334  0.4513E+04  0.4599E-01
      61060.   279.703  0.3316E+04  0.4967E-01   271.845  0.3384E+04  0.4967E-01
      56554.   276.773  0.2394E+04  0.5391E-01   268.172  0.2415E+04  0.5391E-01
      52146.   273.807  0.1824E+04  0.5890E-01   264.389  0.1822E+04  0.5890E-01
      47854.   270.453  0.1444E+04  0.6566E-01   260.364  0.1439E+04  0.6566E-01
      43695.   266.208  0.1117E+04  0.7502E-01   255.938  0.1105E+04  0.7502E-01
      39681.   260.759  0.8309E+03  0.8441E-01   251.280  0.8060E+03  0.8441E-01
      35828.   254.075  0.5863E+03  0.9632E-01   246.411  0.5696E+03  0.9632E-01
      32150.   245.819  0.4035E+03  0.1121E+00   241.346  0.4033E+03  0.1121E+00
      28660.   236.608  0.2694E+03  0.1265E+00   236.187  0.2713E+03  0.1265E+00
      25371.   227.344  0.1296E+03  0.1632E+00   230.684  0.1305E+03  0.1632E+00
      22294.   220.117  0.4962E+02  0.2049E+00   225.186  0.5026E+02  0.2049E+00
      19436.   213.637  0.1507E+02  0.2509E+00   218.768  0.1510E+02  0.2509E+00
      16795.   209.596  0.6088E+01  0.3555E+00   215.204  0.6136E+01  0.3555E+00
      14384.   208.764  0.4290E+01  0.4708E+00   215.839  0.4273E+01  0.4708E+00
      12204.   206.491  0.3246E+01  0.5346E+00   215.683  0.3256E+01  0.5346E+00
      10205.   203.488  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00   215.618  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00
       8518.   202.628  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00   216.410  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00
       6997.   203.765  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01   217.850  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01
       5673.   206.121  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01   219.586  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01
       4529.   209.017  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01   221.315  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01
       3551.   213.993  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01   223.209  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01
       2726.   221.282  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01   225.229  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01
       2040.   227.275  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01   227.716  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01
       1481.   230.002  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01   231.953  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01
       1037.   231.054  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01   237.296  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01
        695.   234.753  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01   244.054  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01
        441.   240.934  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01   252.245  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01
        261.   254.132  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01   262.152  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01
        142.   269.671  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01   273.944  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01
         69.   268.233  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01   273.136  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01
         29.   252.820  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01   258.509  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01
         10.   229.814  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00   230.264  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00
Surface Temperature (K):         296.495   294.210
Surface Humidity (ppmv):      171820.227 18771.500
Skin Temperature (K):            297.397   294.210
Surface Pressure (Pa):           101325.  101325.

No. of Iterations:               4
Normalised Cost Function:      29.081 Normalised Gradient:       0.206
 --------------------------------------------------------------
Obs ID:              4 Obs Type:          2 Satellite ID:    15
Latitude:    20.7500 Longitude:  128.5500 Elevation:        0.0
Surface Type:       1 Sat View Angle:  32.3000 Solar Zen Ang:   55.6000
Brightness Temperatures:
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00         183.26         245.86         267.38         259.01
         239.17         226.73         215.31         205.46         212.86
       -9999.00         233.02         242.80       -9999.00       -9999.00
       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00       -9999.00
 Number of Channels Used =           11
 Channel  Background  Observed   Retrieved          
     22    166.396    183.260    183.424
     23    232.703    245.860    246.894
     24    261.419    267.380    267.614
     25    254.784    259.010    258.388
     26    239.501    239.170    239.636
     27    229.465    226.730    226.062
     28    222.813    215.310    215.964
     29    219.808    205.460    209.652
     30    223.651    212.860    215.099
     32    240.528    233.020    234.234
     33    252.528    242.800    244.615
                          Retrieval                        Background
  Pressure (Pa)  T (K)    q (ppmv)     Ozone        T (K)   q (ppmv)      Ozone
     101325.   298.485  0.2349E+05  0.3016E-01   294.210  0.1877E+05  0.3016E-01
     100543.   297.925  0.2333E+05  0.3037E-01   293.907  0.1841E+05  0.3037E-01
      98588.   297.638  0.2099E+05  0.3090E-01   293.136  0.1751E+05  0.3090E-01
      95744.   295.755  0.1820E+05  0.3170E-01   291.987  0.1621E+05  0.3170E-01
      92246.   294.182  0.1582E+05  0.3274E-01   290.545  0.1465E+05  0.3274E-01
      88280.   293.042  0.1360E+05  0.3397E-01   288.909  0.1299E+05  0.3397E-01
      83995.   291.998  0.1152E+05  0.3541E-01   287.073  0.1126E+05  0.3541E-01
      79509.   290.356  0.9438E+04  0.3726E-01   284.817  0.9380E+04  0.3726E-01
      74912.   287.853  0.7395E+04  0.3973E-01   281.939  0.7414E+04  0.3973E-01
      70273.   285.094  0.5695E+04  0.4271E-01   278.681  0.5757E+04  0.4271E-01
      65643.   282.363  0.4440E+04  0.4599E-01   275.334  0.4513E+04  0.4599E-01
      61060.   279.479  0.3326E+04  0.4967E-01   271.845  0.3384E+04  0.4967E-01
      56554.   276.413  0.2399E+04  0.5391E-01   268.172  0.2415E+04  0.5391E-01
      52146.   273.278  0.1826E+04  0.5890E-01   264.389  0.1822E+04  0.5890E-01
      47854.   269.713  0.1445E+04  0.6566E-01   260.364  0.1439E+04  0.6566E-01
      43695.   265.274  0.1118E+04  0.7502E-01   255.938  0.1105E+04  0.7502E-01
      39681.   259.677  0.8317E+03  0.8441E-01   251.280  0.8060E+03  0.8441E-01
      35828.   252.908  0.5871E+03  0.9632E-01   246.411  0.5696E+03  0.9632E-01
      32150.   244.760  0.4042E+03  0.1121E+00   241.346  0.4033E+03  0.1121E+00
      28660.   235.817  0.2699E+03  0.1265E+00   236.187  0.2713E+03  0.1265E+00
      25371.   226.915  0.1298E+03  0.1632E+00   230.684  0.1305E+03  0.1632E+00
      22294.   219.987  0.4972E+02  0.2049E+00   225.186  0.5026E+02  0.2049E+00
      19436.   213.622  0.1509E+02  0.2509E+00   218.768  0.1510E+02  0.2509E+00
      16795.   209.594  0.6095E+01  0.3555E+00   215.204  0.6136E+01  0.3555E+00
      14384.   208.769  0.4289E+01  0.4708E+00   215.839  0.4273E+01  0.4708E+00
      12204.   206.557  0.3248E+01  0.5346E+00   215.683  0.3256E+01  0.5346E+00
      10205.   203.706  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00   215.618  0.3268E+01  0.6454E+00
       8518.   203.004  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00   216.410  0.3151E+01  0.8814E+00
       6997.   204.221  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01   217.850  0.3197E+01  0.1477E+01
       5673.   206.557  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01   219.586  0.3345E+01  0.2127E+01
       4529.   209.361  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01   221.315  0.3556E+01  0.2778E+01
       3551.   214.185  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01   223.209  0.3914E+01  0.3599E+01
       2726.   221.298  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01   225.229  0.4219E+01  0.4880E+01
       2040.   227.202  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01   227.716  0.4417E+01  0.5843E+01
       1481.   229.983  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01   231.953  0.4622E+01  0.6661E+01
       1037.   231.087  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01   237.296  0.4813E+01  0.7761E+01
        695.   234.593  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01   244.054  0.4936E+01  0.8816E+01
        441.   240.428  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01   252.245  0.5009E+01  0.8578E+01
        261.   253.545  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01   262.152  0.5248E+01  0.6310E+01
        142.   269.375  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01   273.944  0.5492E+01  0.3771E+01
         69.   267.973  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01   273.136  0.5443E+01  0.2200E+01
         29.   252.604  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01   258.509  0.5046E+01  0.1346E+01
         10.   229.799  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00   230.264  0.4082E+01  0.6941E+00
Surface Temperature (K):         296.589   294.210
Surface Humidity (ppmv):      173522.174 18771.500
Skin Temperature (K):            297.755   294.210
Surface Pressure (Pa):           101325.  101325.

No. of Iterations:               4
Normalised Cost Function:      28.182 Normalised Gradient:       0.529
 --------------------------------------------------------------
```

Первые мои попытки это было использование регулярных выражений.

```html
Obs ID:.*?(\d+).*?Obs Type:.*?(\d+).*?Satellite ID:.*?(\d+)
Latitude:.*?([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.]).*?Longitude:.*?([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.]).*?Elevation:.*?([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])
Surface Type:.*?(\d+).*?Sat View Angle:.*?([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.]).*?Solar Zen Ang:.*?([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])\n
```

После некоторого анализа у меня появился кое какой код.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

rx_dict = {
    'coords': re.compile(r'.*?(?P<latitude>([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])).*?Longitude:.*?(?P<longitude>([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.])).*?Elevation:.*?(?P<elevation>([+-]?\d*.\d+)(?![-+0-9\\.]))'),
    'Table': re.compile(r'(?P<Table>.*?Retrieval.*?Background)'),
}


def _parse_line(line):

    for key, rx in rx_dict.items():
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            return key, match
    # if there are no matches
    return None, None


def parse_file(filepath):

    data = []  # создать пустой список для сбора данных
    # откройте файл и прочитайте его построчно
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file_object:
        line = file_object.readline()
        while line:
            # в каждой строке проверяйте совпадение с регулярным выражением
            key, match = _parse_line(line)

            # извлечь знаения coords
            if key == 'coords':
                coords = match.group('latitude','longitude','elevation')
            # извлечь знаения Table
            if key == "Table":
                table = []
                line = file_object.readline()
                i = 0
                while line.strip():
                    if i < 44:
                        table.append(line)
                        i=i+1
                        line = file_object.readline()
                    else:
                        break
                while line.strip():
                    row = {
                        'coords': coords,
                        'Table':table,
                    }

                    # добавить словарь в список данных
                    data.append(row)
                    line = file_object.readline()

            line = file_object.readline()

        # create a pandas DataFrame из списка диктов
        #data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filepath = 'File\\test.profiles'
    data = parse_file(filepath)
    print(data)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'coords': ('20.7500', '124.5500', '0.0'), 
'Table': ['  Pressure (Pa)  T (K)    q (ppmv)     Ozone        T (K)   q (ppmv)      Ozone\n', 
'     101325.   298.686  0.2324E+05  0.3016E-01   294.210  0.1877E+05  0.3016E-01\n', 
'     100543.   298.024  0.2315E+05  0.3037E-01   293.907  0.1841E+05  0.3037E-01\n', 
'      98588.   297.515  0.2113E+05  0.3090E-01   293.136  0.1751E+05  0.3090E-01\n', 
'      95744.   295.335  0.1864E+05  0.3170E-01   291.987  0.1621E+05  0.3170E-01\n', 
'      92246.   293.676  0.1643E+05  0.3274E-01   290.545  0.1465E+05  0.3274E-01\n', 
'      88280.   292.650  0.1426E+05  0.3397E-01   288.909  0.1299E+05  0.3397E-01\n', 
...............
```

Как лучше всего форматировать таблицу в читаемый вид?

Comment: может код ваш покажите?

Comment: Вам нужно прям все данные вытащить, или только Obs ID, Latitude и Surface Type?

Comment: @strawdog, Цель преобразовать данные в csv файл для дальнейшего анализа.

Comment: @michael_best, В данный момент я изучаю библиотеку re и стараюсь следовать примеру https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982949/how-to-parse-complex-text-files-using-python

Comment: Лучше, наверное, привязаться к заголовкам, и, построчно читая, парсить данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как здесь посоветовали, лучше действительно привязываться к заголовкам и парсить части файла в зависимости от заголовков. Однако, для таблиц я бы рекомендовал воспользоваться pandas - это и быстрее, и намного удобнее, чем писать регулярки. То есть, алгоритм таков: нашли заголовок - считали файл от этого заголовка до следующего в переменную, а затем запихнули содержимое этой переменной в дейтафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

buf = StringIO('''
 101325.   298.686  0.2324E+05  0.3016E-01   294.210  0.1877E+05  0.3016E-01
 100543.   298.024  0.2315E+05  0.3037E-01   293.907  0.1841E+05  0.3037E-01
  98588.   297.515  0.2113E+05  0.3090E-01   293.136  0.1751E+05  0.3090E-01
  95744.   295.335  0.1864E+05  0.3170E-01   291.987  0.1621E+05  0.3170E-01
  92246.   293.676  0.1643E+05  0.3274E-01   290.545  0.1465E+05  0.3274E-01
  88280.   292.650  0.1426E+05  0.3397E-01   288.909  0.1299E+05  0.3397E-01
  83995.   291.770  0.1209E+05  0.3541E-01   287.073  0.1126E+05  0.3541E-01
''')

buf1 = StringIO('''
Surface Temperature (K):         296.249   294.210
Surface Humidity (ppmv):      149826.209 18771.500
Skin Temperature (K):            296.738   294.210
Surface Pressure (Pa):           101325.  101325.
''')

df = pd.read_csv(buf, header=None, sep="\s+", skipinitialspace=True)
print(df)
df1 = pd.read_csv(buf1, header=None, sep="\s+", skipinitialspace=True)
print(df1)
```

Результат принтов:

```
          0        1        2        3        4        5        6
0  101325.0  298.686  23240.0  0.03016  294.210  18770.0  0.03016
1  100543.0  298.024  23150.0  0.03037  293.907  18410.0  0.03037
2   98588.0  297.515  21130.0  0.03090  293.136  17510.0  0.03090
3   95744.0  295.335  18640.0  0.03170  291.987  16210.0  0.03170
4   92246.0  293.676  16430.0  0.03274  290.545  14650.0  0.03274
5   88280.0  292.650  14260.0  0.03397  288.909  12990.0  0.03397
6   83995.0  291.770  12090.0  0.03541  287.073  11260.0  0.03541

         0            1        2           3          4
0  Surface  Temperature     (K):     296.249     294.21
1  Surface     Humidity  (ppmv):  149826.209   18771.50
2     Skin  Temperature     (K):     296.738     294.21
3  Surface     Pressure    (Pa):  101325.000  101325.00
```

Единственное - это нужно будет поплясать с заголовками столбцов в дейтафреймах, но, если у вас несколько однотипных наборов данных, то оно того стОит.